# Put array into angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have got a piece of code in an angular application, that writes a navigation tree into a `<div>`. This tree may change its size depending on the model of `mymodule.tree.folders`. Now I want to write a directive `class="scrollable"`, that adds the functionality of [jquery.nicescroll](http://nicescroll.areaaperta.com/) to the wrapping `<div>`:

```
<div class="scrollable">
    ... here is my resizing tree ...
</div>
```

Now, I have to call the `resize()` function of nicescroll each time, the tree model `mymodule.tree.folders` changes. This is necessary to make this library work as expected, after the content changes its size.

My question now is: How do I put the model `mymodule.tree.folders` (it is an array) into my directive to be able to `$watch()` it there? I would like to write something like this:

```
<div class="scrollable" scrollable-watch="mymodule.tree.folders">
    ... here is my resizing tree ...
</div>
```

...in my template. Is this possible, to fetch this model from the templates scope or do I have to serialize the whole tree into an extra variable?

Comment: so you want to resize every time mymodule.tree.folders changes

Comment: Yes. Or, better said: call the resize() function of the scrolling library to tell it, that the container has been resized. :)

Comment: You are still using jquery under angularjs. I don't think this is a good way to solve problems but i appreciate  your effort =)

Comment: Yes. We're using $.getJSON and this scrolling jquery plugin. $.getJSON is capsuled into a thin service, that don't needs to be tested and can be easily be replaced in the tests and the scrollable directive doesn't require testing, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to access the model through the `$parent` scope:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('shared.directives.scrollable', []);

angular.module('shared.directives.scrollable').directive('scrollable', function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('$parent.' + attrs.scrollableWatch, function(newValue, oldValue) {
                console.log('Model changed!');
            }, true);
        }
    };
});
```

It seems a bit hackish to access the parent scope, but because this is allways the caller scope, I think it is okay.